# Checking if a variable is undefined returns the variable is undefined

Tags: javascript

I have a statement in my code:

```
if(!(typeof options.duration[i] === 'undefined'))
```

I have written it correctly, seems that there is no mistake but the console is throwing error that:

```
TypeError: options.duration is undefined
```

It should not show this error.It does not make any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `options.duration` is undefined, so accessing item `i` from it will result in this error. Perhaps try:

```
if(typeof options.duration !== 'undefined')
```

Or if you need to check both `options.duration` and `options.duration[i]`, try

```
if(typeof options.duration !== 'undefined' &&
   typeof options.duration[i] !== 'undefined')
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Plus, I think you should add `()` around both conditions.

Comment: @MuhammedTalhaAkbar That's not necessary, but if you find it makes the code more readable, then yes, you can put the parentheses around each condition.

Answer (score 1):

For your test to succeed, the array `options.duration` must itself also be defined.

Comment: And `options` as well

Comment: @Johan it is not necessary because it is surely defined. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You get that error because the `duration` property doesn't exist.

Check if the property exists before you try to check items in it:

```
if('duration' in options && typeof options.duration[i] !== 'undefined')
```